# Windows 10 Enterprise 1803: how to associate AD account used for login to Microsoft account

Tags: user-accounts, microsoft-account, windows-10-v1803

I've installed version 1803 (windows 10 enterpise) to my PC and it seems like the option to connect my AD account (my PC was added to a domain and my domain account was added to the local Admin group) to a Microsoft account is gone. Previously, there was an option to connect your [account to an existing Microsoft account](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_security/how-to-connect-to-a-microsoft-account-in-windows/c1614fe6-a9cd-4723-a9e0-7293d9cdfd4a). As you can see, it seems like that option is gone now:

[image]

SO, is this option really gone? Or is it gone because it's controlled by some sort of domain policy? What am I missing?

thanks,

Regards,
Luis

Comment: IIRC this isn’t possible with domain accounts and never was. Can’t find reliable info on that though.

Comment: Linking a Microsoft Account to a user profile has always only worked with a local user account Microsoft not an Active Directory domain user account

Comment: That's weird...I had it working previously, before formatting the machine in order to install 1803...not sure if it was initially set up when I used windows 8.1 and then it stayed like that  after upgrading to windows 10 or if I managed to do it already on the first version windows 10...

Comment: btw, I did find this discussion, but didn't work in my case: https://superuser.com/questions/930681/how-to-link-windows-10-domain-user-account-to-microsoft-account?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: and also this discussion: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/040c5d1e-01bf-4952-bb00-88e9779e53da/how-link-windows-domain-id-with-microsoft-account-in-windows-10-1709?forum=win10itpronetworking